# How to entered only numbers not allowed letters or special characters in asp.net using regular expression?

Tags: asp.net

i used this asp.net code it will accept but not validate special character for example.
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

Comment: Do you want to allow users to enter only numbers.No letters and special characters are allowed.Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly have a look at some [Regular Expression Basics](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).Try using `^[0-9]*$` , this will accept only numbers from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 $('input').keyup( function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.val($this.val().replace(/[^0-9]/*$, ''));
```

});